# How can I get email notification when I get or make a Ripple payment?

Tags: ripple

What's the easiest way to get an email notification whenever I receive or send a Ripple payment?

Comment: The Ripple API is public, you can either write your own tool to do this or you could try posting on the Ripple forums to encourage someone else to provide such a service publicly.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my service, [Was I Paid?](https://wasipaid.com). It will send you an email on payment receipt, and in the future will support other types of events.

Answer (score 1):

Write a node.js app, using [this](https://github.com/ripple/ripple-lib) and [this](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer). Subscribe to account transactions, and send an email whenever something happens.